# Comparing approaches for updating Firestore fields

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Looking for recommendations to optimize mechanism for updating a Firestore db field in response to a comparison of separate fields in the same document. The mechanism is for the user supplying a verification code then the back end process flags the document as verified.

Option 1) Run a Node.js environment - This has a Collection Snapshot looking for updates then comparing specific document field values then updating the 'verified' field if they match.

```
console.log("listen.js - listening for order submissions in the db...")
db.collection(dbPath)
  .where('code', '!=', 'XXXX')
  .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    var items = [];
    var index = 0;
    console.log("Listening ... dbPath = ", dbPath)
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

      const ref = db.collection(dbPath).doc(doc.id);
      if (doc.data().code === doc.data().resp) {
        ref.update({ verified: true })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log("Verified resp:", res)
          })
      }
    });
  });
```

Option 2) Use Firebase Cloud Functions - There doesn't seem to be a way to monitor for an individual field so checks for any update to the overall document then pulls the whole document data for a comparison of the required fields then performs an update to the 'verified' field

```
  exports.verify = functions.firestore
  .document('contacts/{bid}/orders/{oid}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {

    const { userId, bid, oid } = context.params;
    console.log("Params:", context.params)

    const newValue = change.after.data() || {};
    if (newValue.code === newValue.resp) {
     
      console.log("Code verified")
      // Update verified flag
      const document = firestore.doc(`contacts/${bid}/orders/${oid}`);
      document.update({
        verified: true
      });
      return "Verified"
    } else {
      // perform desired operations ...
      console.log("Code not verified...")
      return "No"
    }

  });
```

The questions is which of these is a better option from:
a) Process and resource efficiency - The Cloud Functions option pulls the whole document then does the compare of the required fields. The Node environment appears to do a more precise query on less data.
b) Cost/environment overheads - Is a relatively small Node environment running this process less costly than the Cloud Function running and verifying a document. Obviously this will likely depend on the number of operations (and orders processed) so could add up with high usage.

I know there are a couple of 'it-depends' answers but are there any general thoughts on a Cloud Function vs dedicated Node.js process environment. How might efficiency and cost vary as load/usage increases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make it clear. In both cases you would read a whole `document` if just one of them get triggered by a change. So if you watch that both of them would give you the same amount of reads.

Regarding performance I would "personaly" stick with the Cloud Functions. Your scenario sounds like a perfect fit for it. Like a job for what the Cloud Functions are made for.

If you have free backend resources to run and leave your node.js solution up and runing, updating, securing etc... you would save some of your money by reducing the Cloud Functions triggers amount. But when listening to your scenario it doesn't sound like something happening so often that should give you fear.

I would be more afraid of a constantly listening collection listener checking for changes and keeping that thing up and running 24/7.